# Flutter 3 positional argument(s) expected, but 2 found. Try adding the missing arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this model:

```
class ElementTask {
  final String name;
  final bool isDone;
  ElementTask(this.name, this.isDone);
}
```

Now I want to add:

```
final int frequency;
```

But then I get this error in my other class:

**3 positional argument(s) expected, but 2 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.**

I am using this code:

```
 getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<ElementTask> listElement = [];
    int nbIsDone = 0;

    if (widget.user.uid.isNotEmpty) {
      // ignore: missing_return
      snapshot.data.documents.map<Column>((f) {
        if (f.documentID == widget.currentList.keys.elementAt(widget.i)) {
          f.data.forEach((a, b) { //<--error here**
            if (b.runtimeType == bool) {
              listElement.add(ElementTask(a, b));
            }
          });
        }
      }).toList();

      for (var i in listElement) {
        if (i.isDone) {
          nbIsDone++;
        }
      }
```

What can I do to solve it? Should I add a c or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to make `frequency` optional, make it nullable. and use named argument.

```dart
class ElementTask {
  final String name;
  final bool isDone;
  final int? frequency;
  ElementTask(this.name, this.isDone,{this.frequency});
}
```

If you like to have it required, you need to pass three item.

More about [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)

Comment: okey. can I use my code to pass 3 items? or do I need to replace it with other code?

Comment: You can also pass three argument here like `ElementTask("name", false, frequency: 12);` first two of them are positional argument the way you are using right now. last one is optional positional argument.

Answer (score -1):

I got this exception when I did not put coma between arguments:

```
Logger.log('Main', 'onBackgroundEvent'  'notifications initialized');
```

(There is a coma expected between `onBackgroundEvent` and `notifications initialized`)